# HAXM device is not found

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Установил HAXM. Опция "Virtualization..." в BIOS-е включена. Но при запуске модуля (Shift+F10) в Android Studio, выходить ошибка HAXM device is not found. 
Проверил через cmd, командой sc query intelhaxm, выходить что "Указанная служба не установлена". Хотя я и через само Android Studio и отдельно через сайт установил установщик HAXM. Как быть? Что делать? Помогите плиз.

Comment: Там где-то надо ещё путь прописать.

Comment: где прописать? не подскажете?